# HTML Input type number Thousand separator

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a thousand separator (e.g. 1,000,000) in my Input field. However, **it has to be of type number** because I need to be able to adjust its value using "step". Code:

```
<input type="number" id='myNumber' value="40,000" step='100'>
```

I tried using Javascript to adjust the value but didn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could create a custom set of controls to control `step`.

Comment: you can try the autoNumeric Plugin http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/

Comment: can't do that in type=number

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "number" input fields will just not work if the value cannot be parsed by `parseFloat()`.

Comment: @Pointy I think that's correct

Comment: Use the function posted in this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773689/how-do-i-add-thousands-separator-to-my-html-form

Comment: @Sushil Unfortunately, autoNumeric does *not* support the input type `number`, as per the [doc](https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric/tree/next#on-which-elements-can-it-be-used)

Answer (score 13):

Using **autoNumeric** plugin you can made a field as numeric input with different separators.

Include plugin:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/autoNumeric/autoNumeric.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Html:

```
 <input type="text" id="DEMO" data-a-sign="" data-a-dec="," data-a-sep="." class="form-control">
```

Script:

```
<script>
 jQuery(function($) {
$('#DEMO').autoNumeric('init');   
 });
</script>
```

You can type only number, if you input 100000,99 you will see 100.000,99.

More: https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric

Comment: I used this plugin. It's great but also buggy. It works fine when you just want to use it in an input element but if you want to do some other things with the input (with JavaScript), it would work in a peculiar way! Bear this in your mind if you want to use it.

Comment: @Mahsa: Yes you're right. But for others who want a solution, we can now use watchExternalChanges:true (default false) to use javascript to manage your inputs (I set value and readonly property).

To initialize like this : 
let optionsDefault = {
        ...
        watchExternalChanges: true, // True when we need to change value by JS. Otherwise, on input hover the value is reset to initial value.
        unformatOnSubmit: true // on form submit, the rawValue are replacing the formatted value to be sent to server
    };
new AutoNumeric.multiple('.auto-numeric', null,  optionsDefault);

Comment: Now in 2022, I used it to format thousands separator for large numbers in input text form. It is great, specially with its option `unformatOnSubmit:true`. However, in my implementation I use some kind of confirm that stop submit a while and I don't have tested it with direct submit yet.

Comment: Please do not suggest JQuery in new code. It's been waaaaay past ECMAScript 6 general support is expected in browsers. Especially that your suggested library could very well work without it at all.

Answer (score 11):

- Check this  [webdesign.tutsplus.com tutorial](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/auto-formatting-input-value--cms-26745)
- Final result is summarized here (look at [direct Codepen playground](https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/PzpoWK))

  ```
  $("#formInput".on("keyup", function(event ) {                   
      // When user select text in the document, also abort.
      var selection = window.getSelection().toString(); 
      if (selection !== '') {
          return; 
      }       
      // When the arrow keys are pressed, abort.
      if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, [38, 40, 37, 39]) !== -1) {
          return; 
      }       
      var $this = $(this);            
      // Get the value.
      var input = $this.val();            
      input = input.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, ""); 
      input = input?parseInt(input, 10):0; 
      $this.val(function () {
          return (input === 0)?"":input.toLocaleString("en-US"); 
      }); 
  });
  ```

**Notes:**

- toLocaleString() javascript function Actually show thousands separator ([example and doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Examples))
- run below code in your console to get the idea

  (30000000).toLocaleString('en-US',{useGrouping:true})

Comment: This is great, thanks.  I modified it a bit to keep the dollar sign in the text field, and allow the up/down arrow to increment and decrement the value by 1000.
https://jsfiddle.net/e3czy926/

Comment: Good solution.  The only drawback is that if a user hits a number key and quickly tabs out of the field, the digit gets added to the input, but the keyup doesn't get hit and the comma is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3):

Create a mask input displaying the formatted number. This solution avoids changing the type or the value of the input.

```js
$("input.mask").each((i,ele)=>{
            let clone=$(ele).clone(false)
            clone.attr("type","text")
            let ele1=$(ele)
            clone.val(Number(ele1.val()).toLocaleString("en"))
            $(ele).after(clone)
            $(ele).hide()
            clone.mouseenter(()=>{

                ele1.show()
                clone.hide()
            })
            setInterval(()=>{
                let newv=Number(ele1.val()).toLocaleString("en")
                if(clone.val()!=newv){
                    clone.val(newv)
                }
            },10)

            $(ele).mouseleave(()=>{
                $(clone).show()
                $(ele1).hide()
            })
            

        })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="mask" type="number" value="12345.678"/>
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution that works fairly well, but I noticed some minor bugs: a) The commas disappear when mousing over the input. b) The field won't stay focused when you put the caret in the field and mouse out of the field. c) Tabbing to focus the field doesn't switch to the numeric input. b and c might be fixed if you change `clone.mouseenter` to `clone.focus`.

Answer (score 2):

You can fake this functionality by using a pseudo-element to display the comma version.

```
div[comma-value]{
  position:relative;
}
div[comma-value]:before{
  content: attr(comma-value);
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}
div[comma-value] input{
  color:#fff;
}
```

A wrapping div is required because inputs can't have pseudo elements.

```
<div>
  <input type="number" id='myNumber' value="40000" step='100'>
</div>
```

And a little bit of JavaScript to insert commas every third character

```
myNumber.value = commify(myNumber.value)
myNumber.addEventListener("change", function(){
  commify(event.target.value)
})

function commify(value){
  var chars = value.split("").reverse()
  var withCommas = []
  for(var i = 1; i <= chars.length; i++ ){
    withCommas.push(chars[i-1])
    if(i%3==0 && i != chars.length ){  
      withCommas.push(",")
    }
  }
  var val = withCommas.reverse().join("")
  myNumber.parentNode.setAttribute("comma-value",val)
}
```

Check out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnru2qtb/)

Comment: Can't see the process of input, so maybe a little modification is needed.

Comment: The issues with this are:
The user can type in a value and the pseudo field isn't updated(you could add an additional change listener to fix this), and;
You can still highlight the white text of the number field.

All in all, this isn't a user or browser friendly solution

Comment: I personally don't like this. Try to highlight the content of the input and you'll see for yourself.

Comment: This works in Chrome but not in FF. Haven't tried in other browsers.

Comment: It should, at least, test if the number is >= 1000 or <= -1000 ... or else it will fail: http://i.imgur.com/BAfWzaQ.png.

Comment: You can't edit the value, and what if they need decimals - this really doesn't work with French or Indian numbers

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to pull it off after modifying https://stackoverflow.com/a/70726755/4829915 because:

1. The code didn't actually add commas due to not using `Number()`.
2. It deleted the entire field when the initial value was blank.
3. No demo was provided.
4. Not saying the original approach was wrong or not, but I chose to use `onfocus` and `onblur` directly on the input itself.

Therefore, here's a revised answer:

- Start with `<input type="text">`. You can still add `min`, `max` and `step` properties.
- Add onfocus and onblur handlers to the `<input>` node:

```js
function use_number(node) {
  var empty_val = false;
  const value = node.value;
  if (node.value == '')
    empty_val = true;
  node.type = 'number';
  if (!empty_val)
    node.value = Number(value.replace(/,/g, '')); // or equivalent per locale
}

function use_text(node) {
  var empty_val = false;
  const value = Number(node.value);
  if (node.value == '')
    empty_val = true;
  node.type = 'text';
  if (!empty_val)
    node.value = value.toLocaleString('en');  // or other formatting
}
```

```html
<input type="text" min=0 onfocus="use_number(this)" onblur="use_text(this)">
```

Answer (score 1):

[csq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680982/csq) recommends using the [jQuery autoNumeric plugin](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/#tutorial). I found it to be very easy and intuitive to use.

My only gripe is that it forces `<input type="text">` rather than `<input type="number">`. This means you lose the funcionality of `step`, but you gain users of your site being able to use commas in fields.

I guess you could use expected values of less than 1,000 as `<input type="number">` and values more than 1,000 as `<input type="text">`

Comment: I have not tested whether this is mobile friendly or not. I suspect that it is not

Comment: AutoNumeric supports Android Chrome as it says on their website: https://autonumeric.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

> function addCommas(nStr) { ....

In addition of yovanny's answer I create a Vue component which use this function.

```
    Vue.component("in-n", {
    template:
        `<input @keyup="keyup" @keypress="isNumber($event)" v-model="text" type="text" />`,
    props: ["value"],
    data() {
        return {
            text: ""
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addCommas(nStr) {
            nStr += '';
            x = nStr.split('.');
            x1 = x[0];
            x2 = x.length > 1 ? ',' + x[1] : '';
            var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
            while (rgx.test(x1)) {
                x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
            }
            return x1 + x2;
        },
        isNumber: function (evt) {
            evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
            if ((charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) && charCode !== 46) {
                evt.preventDefault();;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        },
        keyup() {
            this.text = this.addCommas(this.text.replace(/,/g, ''));
            this.$emit("input", parseInt(this.text.replace(/,/g, '')))
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a much simpler answer:

- Start with `<input type="text">`. You can still add min, max and step properties.
- Add onfocus and onblur handlers to the `<input>` node:

```
node.addEventListener('onfocus', () => {
  const value = node.value;
  node.type = 'number';
  node.value = Number(value.replace(/,/g, '')); // or equivalent per locale
});

node.addEventListener('onblur', () => {
  const value = node.value;
  node.type = 'text';
  node.value = value.toLocaleString();  // or other formatting
});
```

When the user selects the input, it will convert to a regular numeric input with thousands separators removed, but with a normal spinner. When the user blurs the input, it reverts to formatted text.

I add an onkeyup handler that blurs the input when the "enter" key is pressed.

Comment: See [revised answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74975765/4829915).

Answer (score 0):

I have updated @CollenZhou answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67295023/6777672 as on mouse leave, input looses focus which is annoying. I have also added all input type numbers to selector as well as class.

```
$('input.thousands-separator, input[type="number"]').each((i,ele)=>{
        let clone=$(ele).clone(false)
        clone.attr('type','text')
        let ele1=$(ele)
        clone.val(Number(ele1.val()).toLocaleString('en'))
        $(ele).after(clone)
        $(ele).hide()
        clone.mouseenter(()=>{
            ele1.show()
            clone.hide()
        })
        setInterval(()=>{
            let newv=Number(ele1.val()).toLocaleString('en')
            if(clone.val()!=newv){
                clone.val(newv)
            }
        },10)

        $(ele).mouseleave((event)=>{
            if ($(ele).is(':focus')) {
                event.preventDefault();
            } else {
                $(clone).show()
                $(ele1).hide()
            }
        })
        $(ele).focusout(()=>{
            $(clone).show()
            $(ele1).hide()
        })
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? ',' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Comment: Can you improve your answer to have it do what OP asks? *"I want to have a thousand separator (e.g. 1,000,000) in my **Input field**."* While your function might work for adding thousands separators to an arbitrary number, your answer doesn't answer OP's question.