# How to format the value of an html5 number input

Tags: html, formatting

I have a requirement to display the value in a number input with a format. In my case it's commas, like 4,444.

Is this possible? because I don't see anything on how to do this.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp
take a look into "number", if you want something more complex, utilize some component

Comment: @fdfey, feel free to answer and state it's not supported. Thanks.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867551/html-input-type-number-thousand-separator

Comment: @zundarz, you know, I'm surprised number formats aren't part of css3? That's a striking omission, huh. https://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/content-formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is, I don't support formatting. I use the unformatted number in the input.