# InputBox not allowing certain ASCII control characters

Tags: vba, inputbox

Currently working with this string that has embedded ASCII control charters.

```
[)><RS>06<GS>17V0B100<GS>1PRID-001-A1<GS>S99999<RS><EOT>
```

Below filters out the record separators correctly

```
i = InputBox("Test") 'i = [)><RS>06<GS>17V0B100<GS>1PRID-001-A1<GS>S99999<RS><EOT>
i = Split(i, Chr(30)) 
'i(1) = 0617V0B1001PRID-001-A1S99999
```

But group separators do not. Why does the below not split?

```
i = InputBox("Test") 'i = [)><RS>06<GS>17V0B100<GS>1PRID-001-A1<GS>S99999<RS><EOT>
i = Split(i, Chr(29)) 
'i(0) = [)>0617V0B1001PRID-001-A1S99999
```

Comment: @braX chr(29) seems to be getting filtered out by the input-box while chr(30) does not.

Comment: Then it sounds like that should be your question, if the `Split` is irrelevant.

Comment: It's not just an input box issue. The input box was used for my example.

Comment: Well then you may want to clarify your question. I do not think you will get any answers as it is currently explained.

Comment: If you're not using InputBox then what is the problem/question ?

Comment: @TimWilliams Why can I split the record separators(chr(30)) but not the group separators(char(29)) in the above string.

Comment: @Quint Because char(29) is filtered out by InputBox so it's not in `i` to begin with, which should not be a problem if you're not using InputBox?

Comment: @GSerg Do you know of another option for data entry that would not filter out chr(29)?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what's happening during data entry?  Are you copy/pasting from somewhere into a textbox?

Comment: @Quint `VBA.InputBox`?

Comment: @TimWilliams data entry via a barcode scanner. Basically the same situation as the links you provided below.

Comment: Then you may be able to use the solution there - capture the keypress?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the inputbox, this works fine:

```
Dim s As String, arr

s = "[)><RS>06<GS>17V0B100<GS>1PRID-001-A1<GS>S99999<RS><EOT>"

s = Replace(s, "<RS>", Chr(30))
s = Replace(s, "<GS>", Chr(29))

Debug.Print s                         '[)>0617V0B1001PRID-001-A1S99999<EOT>

Debug.Print Split(s, Chr(30))(1)      '0617V0B1001PRID-001-A1S99999

Debug.Print Split(s, Chr(29))(0)      '[)>06
Debug.Print Split(s, Chr(29))(1)      '17V0B100
```

Comment: While inputting the above string with embedded control characters into a textbox, inputbox, ect. I am unable to split it using chr(29) as the delimiter but chr(30) works fine. Chr(29) seems to be getting filtered out.

Comment: Related maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296955/ascii-control-character-html-input-text  and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2d255ecc-9d6c-4df1-8e66-83c01c5802c9/ascii-control-characters-in-a-textbox?forum=winforms

Comment: this is super helpful thank you. Its strange to me that character 29 and 30 don't print the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tim for leading me to the correct answer. Below worked for converting key events to text.

```
Private Sub Text0_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
Dim i As Integer
i = Me.Text0.SelStart
Select Case KeyAscii
    Case 4
        Me.Text0.Text = Me.Text0.Text + "<EOT>"
        Me.Text0.SelStart = i + 5
    Case 29
        Me.Text0.Text = Me.Text0.Text + "<GS>"
        Me.Text0.SelStart = i + 4
    Case 30
        Me.Text0.Text = Me.Text0.Text + "<RS>"
        Me.Text0.SelStart = i + 4
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: `i+4` for the last two?

Comment: Any thing more then 4 works. Cant select more then what is in the text box?

Comment: Why not `VBA.InputBox`?