# HTML Input thousand seperator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a input of type text in a HTML form.

```
<from>
  <input type="text" name="price" value="20000">
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

I want the input text to be displayed comma separated on UI and when the form is submitted, I want the actual value.

If I want to write in javascript as

```
$('form').serialize()
```

then I should get the value for ***price*** as ***20000*** and not ***20,000***

Is this possible without writing any methods in javascript which will parse the comma seperated string to a number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Input type number Thousand separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867551/html-input-type-number-thousand-separator)

Comment: do you want in php

Comment: No, you will need to write code.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible without javascript methods...Try to use **[parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** and **[toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)** method here...

```js
var inputValue = parseInt($("input").val());
$("input").val(inputValue.toLocaleString());
console.log(inputValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="price" value="20000">
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var number=20000;
document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value = number.toLocaleString();
function getValue()
{
  number = +document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value.replace(',', '');
  console.log(number);
}
```

```html
<from>
        <input type="text" name="price">

        <button type="submit" onclick="getValue()">Save</button>
 </form>
```

For more Details

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: This won't work with `$('form').serialize()` as requested.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve like this in php.

```
$output = 49995;
$followers = number_format( $output , 0 , '.' , ',' );
echo $followers;
```

I have given js fiddle like [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k07x1fuL/)