# html Input type number with Thousand Separator

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to add thousand separator on keyup event in input type number
but this work just in 6 character, if more than 6 character, value on input has reseted

this my short code

```
<input type="number" id="tanpa-rupiah" step="any">



var dengan_rupiah = document.getElementById('dengan-rupiah');
    dengan_rupiah.addEventListener('keyup', function(e)
    {
        dengan_rupiah.value = formatRupiah(this.value, 'Rp. ');
    });


 function formatRupiah(bilangan, prefix)
{
    var number_string = bilangan.replace(/[^,\d]/g, '').toString(),
        split   = number_string.split(','),
        sisa    = split[0].length % 3,
        rupiah  = split[0].substr(0, sisa),
        ribuan  = split[0].substr(sisa).match(/\d{1,3}/gi);

    if (ribuan) {
        separator = sisa ? '.' : '';
        rupiah += separator + ribuan.join('.');
    }

    rupiah = split[1] != undefined ? rupiah + ',' + split[1] : rupiah;
    return prefix == undefined ? rupiah : (rupiah ? 'Rp. ' + rupiah : '');
}
```

this my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/C2heg/4619/

Comment: What is your expectation? Upto how much numbers you want it to work?

Comment: as much as possible

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867551/html-input-type-number-thousand-separator

Comment: The problem is that when the number length is grater than 6 it will turn to be i.e. 4.444.444  and point in input type number is for decimal separation an not thousand. So as a number cant have two decimal separators it is discarded.

Comment: You should implement the answer Mamun and VicJordan suggested but replace it with point instead of comma.

Comment: It's breaking because you're trying to hack the number input to display values it doesn't understand (switch it to `type='text'` and it works fine). Don't. Even if it did work you'll run into more problems. Use a text input and add some functionality to make it like a number input.

Comment: @AvistaKautsar check my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

This might suit you. On `keydown` prevent the default action if it is not a number key. On `keyup`, parse the value and update it. Use the `data-` attributes to store and get the original value.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("num");

elem.addEventListener("keydown",function(event){
    var key = event.which;
    if((key<48 || key>57) && key != 8) event.preventDefault();
});

elem.addEventListener("keyup",function(event){
    var value = this.value.replace(/,/g,"");
    this.dataset.currentValue=parseInt(value);
    var caret = value.length-1;
    while((caret-3)>-1)
    {
        caret -= 3;
        value = value.split('');
        value.splice(caret+1,0,",");
        value = value.join('');
    }
    this.value = value;
});

function showValue()
{
  console.log(document.getElementById("num").dataset.currentValue);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num" maxlength="30">
<button onclick="showValue()">Get Value</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have posted answer below. I have added limit of 20 numbers. You can change it as per your need.

You can use [Number.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) for this purpose.

Below is working example:

```js
// When ready.
$(function() {
  var extra = 0;
  var $input = $("#amount");

  $input.on("keyup", function(event) {

    // When user select text in the document, also abort.
    var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    if (selection !== '') {
      return;
    }

    // When the arrow keys are pressed, abort.
    if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, [38, 40, 37, 39]) !== -1) {
      if (event.keyCode == 38) {
        extra = 1000;
      } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        extra = -1000;
      } else {
        return;
      }

    }

    var $this = $(this);
    // Get the value.
    var input = $this.val();
    var input = input.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, "");
    input = input ? parseInt(input, 10) : 0;
    input += extra;
    extra = 0;
    $this.val(function() {
      return (input === 0) ? "" : input.toLocaleString("en-US");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="amount" name="amount" type="text" maxlength="20" />
```

Comment: That's maybe a better way of writing it, but the only real difference here is `type="text"`. That's the reason this isn't breaking.

Comment: @SamVK yes it is always to use native functionality as much as possible for better performance. `Number.toLocaleString()` is very handy for such requirements. True, main problem was of `number` that needs to be `text`.

Answer (score 0):

change your the input type equal to "text" then its work

```
<input type="text" id="tanpa-rupiah" step="any">
```

[checkout jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/C2heg/4647/)

Comment: vijay what is different you are telling here? This is already told by @SamVK in comment.

Comment: sorry i didn't noticed  @SamVK  comment