# .change not working when 'm using toLocaleString on keyup

Tags: javascript

i need some help.

I'm using keyup to format the currency, but when the value reach 1000 or more the .change doesn't work. If i remove the toLocaleString(), the .change works. How can i make both function work? Thank you.

FYI i'm using laravel.

```
$("#amount").change((event) => {
    updateAmountInfo($('#amount').val())
})

// End of Check Balance and Amount //
$("#amount").on("keyup", function(event) {
    checkBalance();
    var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, [38, 40, 37, 39]) !== -1) {
        return;
    }

    var $this = $(this);
    var value = $this.val();

    var input = value.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, "");

    input = input ? Number(input) : 0;
    
    $this.val(function() {
        return (input === 0) ? "" : input.toLocaleString("en-US");
    });
});
```

Comment: You might want to see this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51167308

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I doubt very much that it has anything to do with `toLocalString()`. What happens if you just do `return input === 0 ? "" : input`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.