# thousands separator input type number in react (JSX)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I would like to keep the `<input type="number" />`. All the solutions I have seen want the input type to be text.

I have a form where users type a number (a dollar amount) and want the input to be for example 120,000 rather than 12000 as they are typing.

```
<input
  type="number"
  min="80000"
  max="2000000"
  step="1"
  value={borrowAmount}
  placeholder="value"
  onChange={e => setBorrowAmount(e.target.value)}
/>;
```

Comment: There is too little information here to help you. Include the data and the expected outcome.

Comment: I just added some data, but what I asked for and the expected outcome are self-explanatory. I want thousands separator when the input type is number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML Input type number Thousand separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867551/html-input-type-number-thousand-separator)

Comment: I had seen it before. It uses jquery, so no it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [react-number-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-format)? It can add thousands separators nicely.

```
<NumberFormat 
  thousandSeparator={true} 
  prefix={'$'} 
  value={123456789}
  isAllowed={(values) => {
    const {floatValue} = values;
    return floatValue >= 5 &&  floatValue <= 10000;
  }}
/>
```

The `onValueChange` handler returns an object like this:

```json
{
  "formattedValue": "$123,456,789",
  "value": "123456789",
  "floatValue": 123456789
}
```

Comment: I have tried it. It works, however the reason I want to use <input type="text"/> is that I can parameters like min and max which gives me form validation.

Comment: @HesamAlavi you can use the isAllowed prop in place of min and max

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple approach:

```
const currencyFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(window.navigator.language, {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
});
const FormattedInput = ({value, setValue, minValue, maxValue}) => {
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={currencyFormatter.format(value)}
      onChange={(e) => {
        const nextValue = e.target.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
        setValue(Math.min(maxValue, Math.max(minValue, parseFloat(nextValue === '' ? '0' : nextValue))));  
      }}
    />
  )
}
```