# How to add point to input type number when numbers are on thousand

Tags: javascript, html, css, attributes, numbers

I have an input to define minimum and maximum prices of products.
When I write 10.000, there seems 10000. So, I want to add point to numbers automaticly and show it like 10.000.

I tried these:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01">
<input type="number" step=".01">
<input type="number" step="any">
```

But they ain't work at any all.

Comment: so you always want the value to 3 decimals?

Comment: Doesn't matter. 1.000, 10.000, 100.000.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option using a text field that forces numeric input

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('input.numeric').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('input', e => {
    let n = e.target.value.replaceAll(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".")
    e.target.value = n;
  }))
})
```

```html
<input type="text" class='numeric'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps.

```js
document.querySelector("input")
.addEventListener("change", e => {
  e.target.value = parseFloat(e.target.value)
      .toFixed(3);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" value="0.000" step="0.001">
```

Comment: dude, I want for thousands. I mean, I want to show 1 thousand like 1.000

Comment: it was not clear from your question what you wanted. Review this for masking input field to have a desired appearance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867551/html-input-type-number-thousand-separator you will notice they use `.toLocaleString("en")`, you would instead use  `.toLocaleString('de-DE')`