# How can I solve this: Field error in object 'invoice' on field 'demandaPonta': rejected value ["kWh:1.582,05"];

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I would like you to help me solve this, I have a form that I am using the jquery maskMoney mask, but in my invoice class I have some attributes modeled as double and in the view a string is being sent, how can I handle this? Remembering I need the persisted data to be numbers and not strings, below is my view code and my class modeling:

***accessor methods are created together with HashCode and Equals.***

HTML:

```
<form th:action="cadastrar" method="post" th:object="${fatura}">
                           
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12">
<label for="demandaPonta">Demanda Ponta:</label>
<input type="text"  class="form-control" id="demandaPonta" autocomplete="off" th:field="*{demandaPontaKW}" placeholder="kWh: 0,00">
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12">
<label for="demandaForaPonta">Demanda Fora Ponta:</label>
<input type="text"  class="form-control" id="demandaForaPonta" autocomplete="off" th:field="*{demandaForaPontaKW}" placeholder="kWh: 0,00">
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#demandaPonta').maskMoney({
prefix: 'kWh: ',
allowNegative: false,
thousands: '.', decimal: ',',
affixesStay: true
 });
$('#demandaForaPonta').maskMoney({
  prefix: 'kWh: ',
  allowNegative: false,
  thousands: '.', decimal: ',',
  affixesStay: true
});
```

Class invoice:

```
@Entity
public class Fatura {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "demanda_ponta_kw")
    private Double demandaPontaKW;

    @Column(name = "demanda_fora_ponta_kw")
    private Double demandaForaPontaKW;
}
```

How can I persist the data without having to change the type of my attributes to String? Remembering that I'm using thymeleaf, jpa, spring boot and mysql in the Database

Comment: Format the HTML and Jquery code

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Align it more to the left

Comment: Done, sorry guy

Comment: This related question might offer some help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867551/html-input-type-number-thousand-separator

Comment: unfortunately the article didn't help because my problem is in the persistence of the data, because if I send a string in the view it will always receive an exception