# How do I display input tag with thousand seperation for number in Razor file?

Tags: blazor

I have two input tags with type="number" in a Razor file.

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="salary">Salary:</label>
        <input type="number" id="salary" @bind="formattedSalary" style="text-align: right;" @oninput="FormatSalary" />

    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="familydeduction">Family Deduction:</label>
        <input type="number" id="familydeduction" @bind="_familydeduction" style="text-align: right;" step="any" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```cs
private async Task FormatSalary(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var cleanedSalary = new string(formattedSalary.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
    _salary = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cleanedSalary) ? int.Parse(cleanedSalary) : 0; 
    await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("formatNumber", "salary");      
    await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("formatNumber", "salary");
}
```

```cs
function formatNumber(id) {
    const input = document.getElementById(id);
    const value = input.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    input.value = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(value);
}
```

I've tried to use JavaScript, but it is not working well.

So I am curious if there is any way I can display the separation command in itself (C# Razor file syntax) in real-time.

Comment: can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867551/html-input-type-number-thousand-separator#:~:text=You%20can%20type%20only%20number,you%20will%20see%20100.000%2C99.&text=You%20can%20fake%20this%20functionality,to%20display%20the%20comma%20version.&text=A%20wrapping%20div%20is%20required,can't%20have%20pseudo%20elements.&text=Create%20a%20mask%20input%20displaying%20the%20formatted%20number.

Comment: @Gayantha Thx. It looks like JavaScript is the only answer for this matter. I will look over those link. Again Thx.

Comment: Comma separation is not supported with `type=number`, consider using `type=text` instead.

Comment: @Suprabhat Biswal I can't find any reference for that type=text. So could you inform me where I can find if you have time?

Comment: @sayditto: There is a blog post about `input=number` that explains the allowed characters. Please take a look to gain a better understanding of how numbers work. [Why the number input is the worst input](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/12/26/why-the-number-input-is-the-worst-input/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call js function and get value return as follows,

Razor Page

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="salary">Salary:</label>
        <input type="text" id="salary" @bind="Salary" style="text-align: right;" @onblur="FormatSalary" />

    </div>
</div>

@code{

    public string Salary { get; set; }    

    private async Task FormatSalary()
    {        
        var interopResult = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("formatSalary", Salary);
        Salary = interopResult;
    }
}
```

Input type needs to be `text` instead of a number as @Suprabhat suggested.

Js File

```
window.formatSalary = (salary) => {
    if (salary != null)
        return salary.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
};
```

Make sure to register your js file in index.html or appropriate page.

Result:

[image]

Ref: [Call JavaScript functions from .NET methods in ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: wow...is it so simply thing? thx a lot..really.