add comma in every 3 character and dot for decimal base on users input in js
i have this problem when i tried to input numbers the return value is this (1,2,3,4,5,6,789.99)
i tried this code:
<input type="text" name="deir_applied_amnt" class="form-control" onkeyup="this.value=addcommas(this.value);" placeholder="0.00" >

function addcommas(number) {
    const str = number.toString();
      const regex = /(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?:\.|$))/g; // Insert commas every 3 digits
      const formattedStr = str.replace(regex, '$1,');
      const decimalIndex = formattedStr.indexOf('.');
      if (decimalIndex !== -1) {
        formattedStr = formattedStr.substring(0, decimalIndex) + '.' + formattedStr.substring(decimalIndex);
      }
      return formattedStr;
  }

im expecting format like this 123,456,789.99
Hope you can help me. Thanks!

the best answer to my problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74975765/10476045
