# How to show numbers in Bilion format and save in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

Am newbie to angular js, Currently my number is 10000000 its show like bilion format number like 10,000,000 how to show like in angular js?

```
<div class="input-group-icon">Max <span class="error">*</span>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input style="border-right:none;" name="investment_amount_max" ng-model="attributes.investment_amount_max" max="{{constants.globalValue.maxNumber}}"
            min="{{attributes.investment_amount_min}}" type="number" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step="0.01" required
            class="form-control input-sm m-bot15" />
        <span style="border-left:none; background:none; border-color:#e2e2e4;" class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">{{programname.country.currency_symbol?programname.country.currency_symbol:'$sss'}}</span>        </div>
    <label for="investment_amount_max" ng-show="submittab1 && attributesForm.investment_amount_max.$error.required" class="error">{{formValidation.required}}</label>
    <label for="investment_amount_max" ng-show="submittab1 && attributesForm.investment_amount_max.$error.min" class="error"> {{formValidation.minMax}} </label>
    <label for="investment_amount_max" ng-show="submittab1 && attributesForm.investment_amount_max.$error.max" class="error"> {{formValidation.numberMax}} </label>
    <label for="investment_amount_min" ng-show="submittab1 && attributesForm.investment_amount_max.$error.number" class="error">{{formValidation.errorNumber}}</label>
</div>
```

How to show that number filter using my above codeing?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

Answer (score 2):

See [angular number filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number)

```js
angular.module('numberFilterExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.val = 10000000000;
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="numberFilterExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <label>Enter number: <input ng-model='val'></label><br>
    Default formatting: <span id='number-default'>{{val | number}}</span><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you're looking for a way to format the number in the input field, I suggest you look up the answers on this thread : [How do I add Thousands separator to my html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773689/how-do-i-add-thousands-separator-to-my-html-form)

Comment: Hi,plz check my above coding,i want to show bilion number inside the text box how to show ? is ng-pattern is correct to show?how to use ng-pattern like?

Comment: So you want to show the formatting in your input field?

Comment: As far as I know, that's not possible in angular, atleast not for input type number. You could do that using regex on input type text like suggested in this [Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773689/how-do-i-add-thousands-separator-to-my-html-form). For input type number, you should try using [Javascript Mask Api](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/js/mask/)

Comment: is there any option to use ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" like these?

Comment: I don't think so, that's only for validation. It will not format the input.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to show it, but here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/4uvTcQVskSii04uEuhTS?p=preview) using a filter.

**html**

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input ng-model="number" />
    {{number | numberFilter}}
  </body>
```

**js**

```
app.filter('numberFilter', function() {
  return function numberWithCommas(input) {
    return input.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The default `number` formatting should give you what you want. So rather then `{{myVal}}`, you would use `{{ myVal | number}}`.

The following snippet will show this in action:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myProg">
    <script>
      angular.module('myProg', [])
        .controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
          $scope.myVal = 1000000000;
        }]);
    </script>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <label>Enter number: <input ng-model='myVal'></label><br>
      Standard: <span id='number-default'>{{myVal}}</span><br>
      Formatted: <span id='number-default'>{{myVal | number}}</span><br>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the result, when you plug that into [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit) (for example), is as follows:
[image]

Comment: is there any option to change ng-pattern?

Comment: @news, you asked about *showing* a number for which the formatting shown is the best option. If you want a filter on input, that's probably a *different* question.

Comment: sry for that,plz give me solution for fillter on input

Comment: @news, I suggest you ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

https://plnkr.co/edit/r15xnq392ZaQbmqIAZT2?p=preview

```
 <script>
     angular.module("myapp",[])
       .controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
        $scope.vars=1909009;      
      })
    </script>

 <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>{{vars |number}}</h1>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Intl.NumberFormat()` default usage:

```
var number = 1000000000;
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat().format(number));
--> 1 000 000 000

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(number));
--> 1,000,000,000
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat